# calculate combination of matrix of probabilities (win rate ranking in game)

Tags: probability, python, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let imagine we have a game with 4 players. And after playing game, we will get ranking of 4 players based on their score, rank 1 is the best, rank 4 is the worst. I have created a model for predicting player ranking. In detail, I have created 2 models for predict who will be in rank1 and rank2 of the game:

- model A predict probabilities for who win in rank 1.
- model B predict probabilities for who win in rank 2.

And all of probability outputs will be in this matrix:

| PlayerID | Rank1(prob) | Rank2(prob) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PlayerA | 0.7 | 0.8 |
| PlayerB | 0.2 | 0.05 |
| PlayerC | 0.05 | 0.1 |
| PlayerD | 0.05 | 0.05 |

Based on above table, how can I calculate probability for this event: "Player A and Player B will be in first 2 ranks" ?
Please help

Comment: Why didn't you fit a model which tells you the probability of a player being in the first two ranks?

Comment: @frank Are yoy saying that we should build a model for predicting probabilities for who win in rank 1-2 ? (Player A,B - B,C - C,D, ...)? In this case, if you have more players, its possible output will grow quickly. Example: If you have 10 players, your possible outcome will be P(10,2)=90. So I like to predict for each rank, then combine it

Comment: hey anyone can help?

Comment: It looks like you predict there is a 110% chance that someone will have rank 1.  How does that happen?  And there is a 150% chance that player A will be in one of the first two ranks--again, what could this possibly mean?  As far as your question goes, you haven't offered any information at all concerning joint outcomes, so could you explain in what sense you hope you might "calculate" them?

Answer (score 2):

As noted by whuber in the comments, the sums of the columns should equal 1, and the sums or rows should not exceed 1. So the following table would make more sense.

| PlayerID | Rank1(prob) | Rank2(prob) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PlayerA | 0.6 | 0.2 |
| PlayerB | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| PlayerC | 0.05 | 0.3 |
| PlayerD | 0.05 | 0.1 |

There is no general way to solve this problem. Different models can result in the same table while the combination of player A, B in the top 2 can differ.

However, if you consider the events independent, in the sense that the probability like $P(\text{player B = 2 given, player B = not 1})$ is independent from which player is in position 1, then you could compute it as

$$\begin{array}{}
P(\text{player A = 1 and player B = 2})& =&  P(\text{player A = 1}) \cdot P(\text{player B = 2 given, player B = not 1})\\& =& 0.6 \cdot \frac{0.4}{1-0.3} = \frac{12}{35}\\
P(\text{player B = 1 and player A = 2})& =&  P(\text{player B = 1}) \cdot P(\text{player A = 2 given, player A = not 1})\\& =& 0.2 \cdot \frac{0.2}{1-0.6} = \frac{1}{10}\\
\end{array}$$

And the probability that both players A and B are in the top 2 is the sum $12/35+1/10 = 31/70$.

But, this is only true if the results are independent. It is often the case that this is not true. For instance, if the player C or D get in the first place, then the probability of player B to be 2nd might be smaller in comparison to when player A is in the first place. Namely when player A is in the first place, then player B has only competition from the weaker player C and D to get into 2nd place. But when player C or D get into first place, then player B has still competition from the strong player A to get into 2nd place.

It would be better to use the entire model to simulate the joint probability rather than the marginal probability and obtain joint probability from the marginals.

You could make a table of 2nd and 1st positions.

---

#### Example case

Let's consider a simple game where the scores of players are distributed as normal distributions with different means and simulate different outcomes. We see that the cases of player A and B in the top 2 are 44% whereas the computation with the above formula gives 40%.

```
              2nd place player
         A        B        C        D   
1st place
  player
   A    0.000000 0.266764 0.164332 0.087792
   B    0.173099 0.000000 0.068322 0.033985
   C    0.078179 0.050197 0.000000 0.016704
   D    0.030360 0.018327 0.011939 0.00
```

R Code

```
set.seed(1)
n = 10^6

### simulate a million games
rank = matrix(rep(0,4*4),4)
for (i in 1:n) {
   x = rnorm(4,1:4,2)
   r = rank(x)
   rank[r[1],r[2]] = rank[r[1],r[2]] + 1
}

### outcome
prop.table(rank)

# observed cases 43.9863%
(rank[1,2]+rank[2,1])/n

# computed cases 40.1323%
sum(rank[1,])/n * sum(rank[,2])/(n-sum(rank[2,]))+
sum(rank[2,])/n * sum(rank[,1])/(n-sum(rank[1,]))

# computed cases 44.6140%
1-(sum(rank[3,])+sum(rank[4,])+sum(rank[,3])+sum(rank[,4])-sum(rank[3,])*sum(rank[,4])/n-sum(rank[4,])*sum(rank[,3])/n)/n
```

In the case that player C and D have only a small chance to be 1st or 2nd, then you could use these probabilities to compute the probability that one of player A or player B is outside the top 2.

$$\begin{array}{}P(\text{A or B in top 2}) &=& 1-P(\text{C and/or D in top 2})\\
&\approx & 1 - P(\text{C 1st}) -  P(\text{C 2nd}) - P(\text{D 1st}) -  P(\text{D 2nd}) + P(\text{C 1st})\cdot P(\text{D 2nd}) + P(\text{D 1st}) \cdot  P(\text{C 2nd})  \end{array}$$

This formula works reasonable with the example above.